# MongoDB Drivers (Query Builder) missing from drivers?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

[image: Drivers]

Hi, I'm trying to update some code to use async with the updated mongo driver that's all going well, However I can't Find QUERY from Mongodb.Drivers.Builders.Query, where's it gone ?  What should i use in it's place ? or is it safe to install the legacy driver with the newer ?

I cannot find the MongoDB.Driver.Builders namespace ???

BTW, here's the query just in case there's something new

```
var queryplaces = Query.WithinCircle("Loc", lon, lat, maxDistanceInRadians);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. a little research about the Update and Query class helped me get to the solution.

**[MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update](https://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Update.htm)

Namespace: MongoDB.Driver.Builders

Assembly: MongoDB.Driver.Legacy (in MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll) Version: 2.0.0**

The MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll was missing in the references.

Hence I installed the Legacy (Official C# driver for MongoDB) package and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to nugget, to get the MongoDB.Drivers.Legacy.dll file, run the command

Install-Package mongodbcsharpdriver from the Package Manager Console.

It worked for my case. PS. I copied the legacy.dll file from then new nuget package folder mongodbcsharpdriver.xxx (where xxx is the version) to MongoDB.Driver.xxx/lib/net4x/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to resolve it by including reference to "(Legacy) Official C# driver for MongoDB". Version 2.4 is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go To "Tools ->  NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console"

**" Install-Package MongoDB.Driver "**
past this command and press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case even after adding all assemblies and references it didn't work.After restarting the application it worked(With all the assemblies in place).